# Pub/Sub StreamingPull not working using Node Client

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-api-nodejs-client, node-streams

I am trying to use StreamingPull from Pub/Sub. There are messages published but I don't see any response. for following code

```
    const {v1 } = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');
    const request = {
        subscription: 'projects/<projectId>/subscriptions/Temp'',
        stream_ack_deadline_seconds: 600
    };

    console.log('Pulling Messages...');
    const stream = await subClient.streamingPull({});
    stream.on('data', response => {
        console.log(response);
    });
    stream.on('error', err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
    stream.on('end', () => {
        console.log("end");
    });
    stream.write(request);
    stream.end();
```

I see the code silently finishing without the response being logged. Is there any attribute I am missing in my request. As per doc of [StreamingPullRequest](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rpc/google.pubsub.v1#streamingpullrequest) nothing else is mandatory. The only usage example is here in the [test files](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/blob/09df70d38bdcd1d8b9d8f2773df25422b9124bd5/test/gapic_subscriber_v1.ts#L1930).

Comment: I'm curious, why are you trying to use streaming pull directly instead of using the Node client library that wraps it? https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#node.js

Comment: I am getting a lot of latency using the wrapper lib which I don’t get in sync pull so wanted to try this out to rule out of its really an SDK issue.

Comment: I think you are going to find that using the streaming pull API directly is going to be very difficult to get right. You will have to reimplement many parts of what are in the library. You'd be better off putting in a support request if you have a support plan or an issue in the [Node library GitHub repo](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub).